How to install pip install torch==2.1.2+cu118 in linux?
I see some people can install pip install torch==2.1.2+cu118 e.g.,:
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/dspy/discussions/818
aiohttp==3.9.3
aioprometheus==23.12.0
aiosignal==1.3.1
alembic==1.13.1
annotated-types==0.6.0
anyio==4.3.0
attrs==23.2.0
backoff==2.2.1
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
cloudpickle==3.0.0
colorlog==6.8.2
datasets==2.14.7
dill==0.3.7
diskcache==5.6.3
distro==1.9.0
dspy-ai==2.4.0
fastapi==0.110.0
filelock==3.13.1
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2023.10.0
greenlet==3.0.3
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.4
httptools==0.6.1
httpx==0.27.0
huggingface-hub==0.21.4
idna==3.6
interegular==0.3.3
Jinja2==3.1.3
joblib==1.3.2
jsonschema==4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
lark==1.1.9
llvmlite==0.42.0
Mako==1.3.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
mpmath==1.3.0
msgpack==1.0.8
multidict==6.0.5
multiprocess==0.70.15
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
networkx==3.2.1
ninja==1.11.1.1
numba==0.59.0
numpy==1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.18.1
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12==12.4.99
nvidia-nvtx-cu12==12.1.105
openai==1.14.1
optuna==3.6.0
orjson==3.9.15
outlines==0.0.30
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.2.1
pillow==10.2.0
plumbum==1.8.2
protobuf==5.26.0
psutil==5.9.8
pyarrow==15.0.2
pyarrow-hotfix==0.6
pydantic==2.5.0
pydantic_core==2.14.1
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
pyzmq==25.1.2
quantile-python==1.1
ray==2.9.3
referencing==0.34.0
regex==2023.12.25
requests==2.31.0
rpds-py==0.18.0
rpyc==6.0.0
safetensors==0.4.2
scipy==1.12.0
sentencepiece==0.2.0
sglang==0.1.12
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.28
starlette==0.36.3
sympy==1.12
tokenizers==0.15.2
torch==2.1.2+cu118
tqdm==4.66.2
transformers==4.38.2
triton==2.1.0
typing_extensions==4.10.0
tzdata==2024.1
ujson==5.9.0
urllib3==2.2.1
uvicorn==0.28.0
uvloop==0.19.0
vllm @ https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/releases/download/v0.2.6/vllm-0.2.6+cu118-cp311-cp311-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=5306437fe5e59d91b705760b82b0e5be91f05c1b92c5b05e29fb8e1bbb6fe577
watchfiles==0.21.0
websockets==12.0
xformers==0.0.23.post1+cu118
xxhash==3.4.1
yarl==1.9.4
zmq==0.0.0

why can't I? I know it says I can't do it:
nload/index.aspx Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver.
(base) brando9@mercury1~/snap-cluster-setup $ pip install torch==2.1.2+cu118
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.1.2+cu118 (from versions: 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.1.2+cu118

I know it's possible. What's my issue?
This command also fails:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia


python version
(snap_cluster_setup_mercury) brando9@mercury1~ $ which python
/lfs/mercury1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/snap_cluster_setup_mercury/bin/python
(snap_cluster_setup_mercury) brando9@mercury1~ $ python --version
Python 3.11.8

My gpu info:
(snap_cluster_setup_mercury) brando9@mercury1~ $ nvidia-smi
Tue Apr 16 10:36:54 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.43.04    Driver Version: 515.43.04    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:4F:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 57%   73C    P2   119W / 140W |  14711MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:52:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 53%   70C    P2   101W / 140W |  14711MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:53:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 57%   74C    P2   110W / 140W |  14735MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:56:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 57%   73C    P2   105W / 140W |  14721MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:57:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 56%   73C    P2   109W / 140W |  14679MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:CE:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 57%   74C    P2   106W / 140W |  14703MiB / 16376MiB |     99%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:D1:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 58%   75C    P2   112W / 140W |  14735MiB / 16376MiB |     98%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:D2:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 57%   74C    P2   114W / 140W |  14721MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   8  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:D5:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 61%   78C    P2   121W / 140W |  14719MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   9  NVIDIA RTX A4000    On   | 00000000:D6:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 60%   77C    P2   114W / 140W |  14671MiB / 16376MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    155680      C   python                           8017MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    196102      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6691MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    155920      C   python                           8009MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    196103      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6699MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A    156147      C   python                           8033MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A    196104      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6699MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A    156234      C   python                           8019MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A    196105      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6699MiB |
|    4   N/A  N/A    157205      C   python                           8017MiB |
|    4   N/A  N/A    196106      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6659MiB |
|    5   N/A  N/A    157439      C   python                           8009MiB |
|    5   N/A  N/A    197119      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6691MiB |
|    6   N/A  N/A    157680      C   python                           8033MiB |
|    6   N/A  N/A    197120      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6699MiB |
|    7   N/A  N/A    157963      C   python                           8019MiB |
|    7   N/A  N/A    197121      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6699MiB |
|    8   N/A  N/A    158471      C   python                           8017MiB |
|    8   N/A  N/A    197122      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6699MiB |
|    9   N/A  N/A    158753      C   python                           8009MiB |
|    9   N/A  N/A    197123      C   ...a3/envs/doremi/bin/python     6659MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I will give this other info but I've seen it be inconsistent in the past...so take it with a grain of salt:
(snap_cluster_setup_mercury) brando9@mercury1~ $ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0


related:

Is DSPy compatible with vllm and how good is DSPy with vllm? #818
: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/dspy/discussions/818
vllm not compatible with 2.2.x if that worked then this wouldn't be an issue for me https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747


Which version of Python are you running?

@Ivan 3.11.8 I added more details in quesitons

The first thing that strikes me is that the maximum CUDA version supported by your driver is 11.7, so your PyTorch installation should be lower or equal.

The command you tried with pip failed because the specific version of PyTorch with CUDA 11.8 support might not be available directly through pip. Instead, using conda is recommended for installing PyTorch with specific CUDA versions.
conda install pytorch==2.1.2 torchvision==0.16.2 torchaudio==2.1.2 pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

I hope this helps I also had the same problem before

I did try that :(
